# Symfony compare form to database

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-validator

How can I compare a form field submitted to the actual database data?

If I use my repository to get a copy of the entity, it actually just gets a copy of the form submitted. I want to know if the data submitted in the form has changed from the form.

```
namespace App\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use \App\Entity\Logistics\CarrierSendle;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class CarrierDescUniqueValidator extends ConstraintValidator {

    /**
     * @var Security
     */
    private $security;

    /**
     * @var Em
     */
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, Security $security) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function validate($object, Constraint $constraint) {
        /* @var $constraint \App\Validator\CarrierDescUnique */
        
        if (!$constraint instanceof CarrierDescUnique) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, CarrierDescUnique::class);
        }
        
        if (null === $object->getDescription() || '' === $object->getDescription()) {
            return;
        }
        
        $repoCurrent = $this->em->getRepository(CarrierSendle::class)
                ->GetCurrentName($this->security->getUser(), $object->getSendleId());
        
        if ($object->getDescription() === $repoCurrent->getDescription()) {
            return;
        }
        
        var_dump($object); var_dump($repoCurrent); die;
        
        ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UnitOfWork() is the answer, found here [Source](https://latteandcode.medium.com/symfony-validate-an-object-based-on-its-previous-version-4b6ca7a85dc6)

This will query the database and not used the cached version injected into the validator.

`$original = $this->em->getUnitOfWork()->getOriginalEntityData($object);`